# Load .ppt file using Google docs viewer Android

Tags: java, android, google-document-viewer

I am trying to read ppt files on my Android app.But every time I run the app it crashes at startActivity().

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Uri pptUri = Uri.parse("/home/waheed/check.ppt");
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setText("open ppt")
            .setType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
            .setStream(pptUri )
            .getIntent()
            .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it:

```
Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.test.myapp", fileFromServer);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileURI, mimetype);
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
```

For package name I have these possible values, depending on the extension of the file:

- com.dwgsee.dwgviewer
- cn.wps.moffice_eng

I must mention that I had some problems with some apps on some versions on my Android, I use 4.2.2 and 4.4.4 Android versions (my tablets have those versions), some apps for DWG opened without a problem on 4.2.2 but not on 4.4.4

Comment: What should I write in place of "filefromServer" and mimetype?

Comment: In my case fileFromServer is a File object that has a file I fetch from a shared folder on the network. In your case it should be a File object pointing to whatever file you want to open. The mimeType parameter is just the type of fiel you want to open, search for it on google, in my case I use application/acad for DWG files or application/pdf for PDF files.

Comment: My app is crashing on the following line..............
 Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.myapplication", newFile);
..................I have added these two lines before this above line....................
File imagePath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "/home/waheed");
 File newFile = new File(imagePath, "check.ppt");

Comment: What does Logcat says when you debug? probably the file doesn't exists . Did you add these lines to your manifest?
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: It crashed again at the same line saying in log cat........................Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: nullpointer... mmhh.. probably the File reference is wrong? 
Verify if the file exists with newFile.exists()

Comment: It says "false":(

Comment: That's your problem, just fix the File object 
try somethign like File newFile = new File("/home/waheed/check.ppt");
if the file is located on the root directory of your device, you can try that.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but nothing changed.I am loading a file from the computer.